# Trouble with server tab while adding Tomcat Server in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, eclipse-wtp

I ran through every site with this kind of problem and couldn't find any solutions.

I try to add Tomcat Server to my Maven Projct in Eclipse. However I even coudn't try to open server tabb. Beside the screen where I'm in plain Java perspective I also tried to open by Java EE perspective and also couldn't.

[image]

Comment: it looks like you used to have the Java EE plug-ins installed, but no longer do. You've not given any information about what versions of anything are invoved, of what's changed since the last time this did work. Can you?

Comment: Well I don't think so other information are important. The main thing is that I can't even open the server tab to add tomcat. I just want to get know how to open that tab. I also tried to do it in java ee perspective but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you paste full stack trace of the exception?